# How do I setup an if checkbox checked statement?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple dynamic checkboxes.  I would like to find out what checkbox was checked in the controller.  How do I do that?  This is what I have.

**HTML**

```
foreach (var items in collection) {
    ...
    <tr><td>
        <input id = "checkbox<%= items.id%>" name ="Checkbox<%= items.id%>" />
    </td></tr>
    ...        
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
foreach (var item in CheckboxList) {
    string id = item.id;
    if (Collection.Request.Form["Checkbox" + id].ToString()) {
        //do stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the checked checkboxes will be returned on the form.

```
if(Collection.Request.Form["Checkbox" + id] != null)
{
  // Checked!
}
```

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#checkbox) (4.01):

> When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful.

Comment: You answered my question thatnks, but do you know how to pull the 'is checked' if all the checkboxes has the same name?

Comment: @user54197 - Not sure, you will have to look at the form collection for that name (I suggest debugging through to that line and checking) to see how the multiple checkboxes are presented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Contains("true") condition as below:

```
if (Collection.Request.Form["Checkbox" + id].Contains("true")) {
    //do stuff...
}
```